# GSON converting a string value into null

Tags: android, json, null, gson

I send a request up to an API and use GSON to convert it into an object.

I then pass it through a `Bundle` and pass it as a `JSON` `String`.

The problem is that before I pass it through the bundle the value looks fine, but when I receive the bundle in the next activity the value is then `Null`

What seems to be the problem here? I am guessing that `GSON` is having some problems parsing out the info.

This is what I see for the string key before I run pass it through the bundle.

> http://XXXXXXXX.XXXXXX.com/%7B%7BSIZE%7D%7D-290x116.jpg

This is what I see after I pass it through the bundle

> http://XXXXXXXX.XXXXXX.com/null

I using the following code to pass it through the bundle:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        bundle.putString("my_model", gson.toJson(searchResult, ModelClass.class));
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(i);
```

This is the code I am using to convert the `JSON` back to an object:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        String myModelJSON = bundle.getString("my_model");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        mMyModel = gson.fromJson(myModelJSON, MyModel.class);=
    }
```

Notice the null at the end

How should I go about fixing this? I am thinking about using `Parcelable` if nothing pans out.

**EDIT**:

Response form API using a rest client app:

> "image_path": "/uploads/image/image02-%7B%7BSIZE%7D%7D-290x116.jpg"

Comment: Try putting a test variable in your bundle like name "test", value "abc". Make sure that your getting it on the other end. Also, check the myModelJsonString to make sure it contains what you expect. What other methods are available on myModel? Try accessing them and see what you get.

Comment: I have tried this already and it works fine. Other methods work fine, like `getName();`

Comment: Ah, all I saw before was the "null". Maybe its some kind of encoding issue caused by the "%" signs? What is the string key? Is it part of the object you're encoding? Or is part of the Gson API? I don't think it's the key to access the string in the bundle, which is "my_model"...

Comment: Also, I'm guessing you tried running the fromJson method before sending it through the intent. Is that where the "http://XXXXXXXX.XXXXXX.com/%7B%7BSIZE%7D%7D-290x116.jpg" is coming from?

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: that is the value for the key, the key is "image_path"

Comment: it's interesting the %7B and %7D are left and right bracket. If you decode them, the string would be "http://XXXXXXXX.XXXXXX.com//{{SIZE}}-290x116.jpg", which doesn't seem valid. Is this what's it's supposed to look like? What does the key look like before encoding?

Comment: Oh good catch let check from a rest client app to see what the full path looks like

Comment: updated question with actual response from API

Comment: actually I just checked again, the API is actually returning the weird percent signs!! I was testing the wrong server, the staging server is returning the % signs the other one is working fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seemed to be that the Object I was passing through the bundle contained lists of Objects within itself, it seems like GSON has issues converting that back to its `POJO` object so I just grabbed the lists and passed those instead like so:

```
bundle.putString("list", gson.toJson(myModelObject.getList()));
```

Then in the next activity I grabbed the list like so:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

// Get List
Type typeEntityListObject = new TypeToken<List<ListObject>>(){}.getType();
mList = gson.fromJson(bundle.getString("list"), typeEntityListObject);
```

Now it doesn't return `Null` anymore but as someone pointed out above the API is returning back a faulty string for the path, at least the stuff is working fine on my end.